# Fast way highlight each 2 rows skipping some columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want highlight each 2 rows skipping the columns `D,J,M,P`

I did it:

```
Dim rangeCOLOR As Range
Dim rangeCOLOR1 As Range
Dim rangeCOLOR2 As Range
Dim rangeCOLOR3 As Range
Dim rangeCOLOR4 As Range

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeCOLOR = Range("A11:C" & lastRow)
rangeCOLOR.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(LIN();2)=1"
rangeCOLOR.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeCOLOR1 = Range("E11:I" & lastRow)
rangeCOLOR1.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(LIN();2)=1"
rangeCOLOR1.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeCOLOR2 = Range("K11:L" & lastRow)
rangeCOLOR2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(LIN();2)=1"
rangeCOLOR2.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeCOLOR3 = Range("N11:O" & lastRow)
rangeCOLOR3.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(LIN();2)=1"
rangeCOLOR3.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rangeCOLOR4 = Range("Q11:T" & lastRow)
rangeCOLOR4.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(LIN();2)=1"
rangeCOLOR4.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
```

It works fine, but the code is too long and make 5 condittional formating. Also i ask if there's another way to do it without using `MOD`, because if i want change the color of one line for example, is faster selecting it and fill with another background. Not possibile with `MOD` active.

Thank you

Comment: If this is working but you're just looking for improvement you might want to try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite simple way to do this:

```vb
Sub EveryOtherRow()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim inrng As Range
    Dim outrng As Range
    Dim interval As Integer
    Set inrng = Application.Selection
    Set inrng = Application.InputBox("Range :", inrng.Address, Type:=8)
    interval = 2
        
    For i = 1 To inrng.Rows.Count Step interval + 1
        Set rng = inrng.Cells(i, 1)
        If outrng Is Nothing Then
            Set outrng = rng
        Else
            Set outrng = Application.Union(outrng, rng)
        End If
    Next
    outrng.EntireRow.Select
   
End Sub
```

Simply change the variable `interval` to adjust what nth rows you want highlighter.
If you'd rather color the rows than select them, you may change `outrng.EntireRow.Select` with `outrng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)`

The input-box allows you to have the function more dynamic. If you wish you could always replace this with a static range value, like `rangeCOLOR`.
It takes you initial selection as basis for `inrng`.

Comment: Nice! But there's a problem. The range is the entire row `A11:T` the number of columns will always change, for this reason need find the last row. Also it have to skip the colmuns `D,J,M,P` as i mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. Then you could go ahead and remove the .EntireRow and change it to fit the columns you require. You could add in a function to find the last column: FinalColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column. Utilize that to apply this to a dynamic column range.

Comment: May you show me a example of that? Also removing the `range selection`. I have a fix range `outrng.Range("A11:T11").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)`(i don't know if is correct) until the last row (`Set inrng = Range("A" & lastrow)` and `lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`)

Comment: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row. Outrng.Range(«A11:T» & lastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(217,217,217). If that was what you meant..